# Is it possible to get prettified symbols in Org-mode source blocks?

Tags: org-mode, prettify-symbols-mode

I have a few symbols in [`prettify-symbols-alist`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PrettySymbol) that improve the appearance of elisp code in my configuration file. I am migrating my configuration file from Elisp to Org-mode and I would like to keep the prettified symbols. Is this possible to achieve in Org mode 8.3?

Answer (score 4):

If you want the symbols to be prettified in the whole org file, just define `prettify-symbols-alist` in the buffer and enable `prettify-symbols-mode`.

But a better solution would ensure that these symbols are prettified **only** in the src blocks (and according to the language mode).  Note that they are when editing the source block through `org-edit-src-code` (since the src block is copied in a buffer in the corresponding major mode).

Looking at how src block fontification works (function `org-src-font-lock-fontify-block` in file `org-src.el`:

1. extract block as a string
2. insert it in a dedicated buffer
3. set language major mode
4. call font-lock-fontify-buffer
5. copy 'face properties from buffer to org buffer
6. mark text in org buffer as font-lock-fontified

And seeing (function `enter prettify-symbols-mode` in file `prog-mode.el`) that symbol prettification relies on `'composition` properties, one can deduce we just need to change `org-src-font-lock-fontify-block` to make it copy `'composition` properties as well.

Here is the modified function (see marked 'Addition' part):

```lisp
(defun org-src-font-lock-fontify-block (lang start end)
  "Fontify code block.
This function is called by emacs automatic fontification, as long
as `org-src-fontify-natively' is non-nil."
  (let ((lang-mode (org-src--get-lang-mode lang)))
    (when (fboundp lang-mode)
      (let ((string (buffer-substring-no-properties start end))
        (modified (buffer-modified-p))
        (org-buffer (current-buffer)) pos next)
    (remove-text-properties start end '(face nil))
    (with-current-buffer
        (get-buffer-create
         (concat " org-src-fontification:" (symbol-name lang-mode)))
      (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
      (insert string " ") ;; so there's a final property change
      (unless (eq major-mode lang-mode) (funcall lang-mode))
      ;; Avoid `font-lock-ensure', which does not display fonts in
      ;; source block.
      (font-lock-fontify-buffer)
      (setq pos (point-min))
      (while (setq next (next-single-property-change pos 'face))
        (put-text-property
         (+ start (1- pos)) (1- (+ start next)) 'face
         (get-text-property pos 'face) org-buffer)
        (setq pos next))
      ;; Addition: also copy 'composition info for prettified symbols
      (setq pos (point-min))
      (while (setq next (next-single-property-change pos 'composition))
        (put-text-property
         (+ start (1- pos)) (1- (+ start next)) 'composition
         (get-text-property pos 'composition) org-buffer)
        (setq pos next))
      ;; End addition
      )
    (add-text-properties
     start end
     '(font-lock-fontified t fontified t font-lock-multiline t))
    (set-buffer-modified-p modified)))))
```

You have to ensure this is loaded after the definition in `org-src.el`.

Answer (score 1):

Org has [native pretty symbol mode](http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-symbols.html) that you can enable with `C-c C-x C-\`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct command for org-mode native prettify symbols, `org-toggle-pretty-entities`, is `C-c C-x \`